# neo4j 212 cypher not navigating previously navigated path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

lets say I want to find out shoppers where I stay.

```
match (s:Shopper {id:"yy35575"})-[:DELIVERY_TO]->(:ZipCode)-[:IS_IN]->(:City)<-[:IS_IN]-(:ZipCode)<-[:DELIVERY_TO]-(s2:Shopper) return count (s2);
```

this returns 38, it seems to exclude the shoppers in the zip code where I stay.

If I do following, I get correct answer of 44. Is there is default behaviour like don't navigate what I have already navigated, and how to override it like we used to do in traversals

```
match (s:Shopper {id:"yy35575"})-[:DELIVERY_TO]->(:ZipCode)-[:IS_IN]->(c:City) with c match (c)<-[:IS_IN]-(:ZipCode)<-[:DELIVERY_TO]-(s2:Shopper) return count (s2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it won't match relations already traversed but in your case, your first query is needlessly long.
There's no need to find the zipcode in the city twice, and unless you need something from City in your return statement, city adds no value to the query "find shoppers where I stay".

Best rewritten as:

```
match (s:Shopper {id:"yy35575"})-[:DELIVERY_TO]->(zip:ZipCode)
with zip
match (s2:Shopper)-[:DELIVERY_TO]->(zip)
where s<>s2
return count(s2)
```

Comment: This leaves out the city - that might be a subtly different result, assuming a shopper doesn't have a delivery to all zipcodes in the same city.

Comment: Try `MATCH (s:Shopper {id:"yy35575"})-[:DELIVERY_TO]->(:ZipCode)-[:IS_IN]->(c:City) MATCH (c:City)<-[:IS_IN]-(:ZipCode)<-[:DELIVERY_TO]-(s2:Shopper) WHERE s2 <> s RETURN count(s2)`. Does seem like a query that could be rather large though - returning every shopper in a whole set of cities.